# Pink and green color on overlay logo

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, hls

I ran into such a problem with hls streaming, adding filters to the overlay logo, but it was smeared with pink and green stripes. Has anyone come across this.

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -re -i <(for f in *.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) \ -i /opt/metal-country_ru/logo-full.png \ -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.011):y=main_h*0.02" \ -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event /opt/metal-country_ru/live/stream.m3u8\`[image]

Comment: Does the overlay look like that throughout the output video?

Comment: "Does the overlay look like that throughout the output video?"
YES

Comment: Add -report and rerun for a few seconds. Verify output has the issue, and share report.